# Adding interval on incoming data from web3 subscription

Tags: web3js

I am trying to set an interval on the incoming data from web3 subscription and use alchemy as provider to avoid rate limit.

I tried adding `setInterval` on the data to do this but it returns undefined when wrapped.

```
this.subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions', (err, data) => {
   if (err) console.log('Failed to connect pending mempool!');
})

setInterval(function() { // `data` returns undefined
   this.subscription.on('data', async (txHash) => {
       // do someting
   }) 
}, 3000);
```

What is the correct way to set interval on incoming data from subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need to use `setInterval` because you are already subscribed to an event that will only poll data when there is any update within the blockchain.

As described in the official [Solidity documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-subscribe.html), this should work for you:

```
let subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions', function(error, result){
   if (!error)
      console.log(result);
   })
   .on("data", function(transaction){
      // do something
   });
```

In fact, when you use `setInterval` to retrieve data, you might potentially be doing just the opposite to what you want to achieve (avoid rate limit), since every 3 seconds, you are repeating the data fetch unnecessarily.

On the other hand, is your requirement listening to all pending transactions? perhaps you want to be listening at a specific log for a certain address, such as:

```
let subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('logs', {
    address: '0x123456..',
    topics: ['0x12345...']
}, function(error, result){
    if (!error)
        console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to get only the data every 3 seconds not every incoming data?

Comment: You could subscribe to an event, and after N seconds, unsubscribe to that event and repeat the process, but this might be even worst, because every N seconds you retrieve all the incoming data again. Perhaps you need to filter the data you want to retrieve: see my last comment on listening to logs instead of all pending transactions.